# PHP strtotime for June returns July

Tags: php

I'm stumped as to why the following PHP strtotime function returns '07' as the month number, rather than '06' when $monthToGet = 'June':

```
$monthToGet = $_GET['mon'];
$monthAsNumber = date('m', strtotime($monthToGet));
```

From searching, it appears it may be due to default date parameters (in this case the day and year) as I haven't specified them. Would that be the cause?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: post all the code please

Comment: If you do `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('June'))`, you get `2012-07-01`. And if you pass in `July`, you'll get `2012-07-31`.  Can't say I can describe the exact reason for this though...

Comment: maybe... today is 31 Jul. So (31) June it's 1 July

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

You are right

```
echo date("m", strtotime("June"));
-> 07
```

However, *this* does work:

```
echo date("m", strtotime("1. June 2012"));
-> 06
```

### The problem explained

Today is `31. July 2012` and since you provide only a month, the current day and current year are used to create a valid date.

See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

> **NOTE**
>
> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

### Alternatives

You could use [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) or [`strptime()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to achieve what you want with a slightly different approach.

(Thanks to johannes_ and johann__ for their input)

Comment: I have gone with this solution, it works. The strtotime function looks like it requires a date and year otherwise it defaults to predefined function values that aren't always correct.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with :

```
$monthToGet = '1 '. $_GET['mon'];
```

But I still don't get why, since "m" is [a valid date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

Today is 31 Jul. So a `strtotime` with only `"June"` is interpreted as `31 June` => `1 July`.

In fact:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("January"));  // 2012-01-31
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("February")); // 2012-03-02
```

of course... only `today 31 Jul 2012` :) Tomorrow all will works.

You're lucky because you found this bug just today ;)